# Ant: copy files from remote Windows directory to local directory

Tags: ant

The remote directory is "\remotemachine\dir1\dir2" or "file://remotemachine/dir1/dir2" in browser， And i have to use username/password to log in the remote machine.
  How to achieve this? any ideas would be appreciated.

p.s. Seems there is a scp task which take care of remote copy but seem only useful in Linux/Unix platform

Comment: Now i confirmed that the remote OS is Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 3 options I can think of for copying remote files:

1. [SCP](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html)
2. [FTP](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html)
3. [GET](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)

Which one you use is really determined by the mechanism you're using to make the file available on the server.

I would always recommend setting up SSH (there are windows sshd implementations available). The protocol is encrypted and you can also use public/private key authentication (More secure than using passwords).